# Add your model on turtlebot gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to make text recognition using an asus camera. I manage to have some results by using Tesseract and extract script and created a script combining them. Now i am trying to simulate it with a turtlebot in gazebo but i dont know how to add a model that has something written on it like a sign that writes stop.. Is there a way to add my own model with text on it or just 2D images?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269102/add-your-model-on-turtlebot-gazebo/) by [Panos686](https://answers.ros.org/users/30486/panos686/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, sure, you can add your own models, also with texture. Here for example I added this table from [rail_collada_models](https://github.com/GT-RAIL/rail_collada_models/tree/develop/meshes/original_models/doll_furniture):

[image: image description]

You need to add it to ~/.gazebo/models with a model.config file describing it. For example for the table above you must add a directory named doll_table containing the meshes and textures and a model.config file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model>
  <name>Doll table</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sdf version='1.3'>doll_table.sdf</sdf>

  <author>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <email>xxx@yyy.zzz</email>
  </author>

  <description>
    A small wooden table.
  </description>
</model>
```

to ~/.gazebo/models. Just check other models there as examples (will be empty until you include some of the models available by default in gazebo; they get downloaded locally the first time you use them).

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panos686](https://answers.ros.org/users/30486/panos686/) on 2017-09-08**:
Sry for the late answer ! Thanks for the help i used the same after all :)